# What's the probability of not choosing a card from all suits in a deck with or without replacement?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

If I have a deck with 5 suits of 14 cards each, what is the chance not drawing at least one card of each suit, after 16 draws **with** replacement?
Using inclusion-exclusion rule:
$$
\binom{5}{1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{16}-\binom{5}{2}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{16}+\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{16}-\binom{5}{4}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{16}\approx0.1379
$$
There's a 4/5 chance to not draw a given suit with $\binom{5}{1}=5$ combinations of suits, 3/5 chance to not draw two given suits with $\binom{5}{2}=10$ combinations of two suits, and so on.

Using the same deck, what is the chance not drawing at least one card of each suit, after 16 draws **without** replacement? Again, using the inclusion-exclusion rule:
$$
\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{56}{16}-\binom{5}{2}\binom{42}{16}+\binom{5}{3}\binom{28}{16}}{\binom{70}{16}}\approx0.08329
$$
There are 70 cards in the deck. If I only choose 4 suits ($\binom{5}{1}=5$ combinations), then there are 56 cards to pick from. If I only choose 3 suits ($\binom{5}{2}=10$ combinations), then there are 42 cards to pick from, etc.  It's not possible to choose only 1 suit as there are 14 cards in a suit and 16 draws, so this term is not included.

It's surprising to me that there's this large of a difference between the two. I know that there is some self-correction in the non-replacement case; while the probability of choosing each suit is 1/5 to begin with, as soon as you draw a card, the probability of drawing its suit again decreases while that of the others' increases. I didn't think this self-correction would have as big of an impact as it seems to, so it makes me wonder if I calculated everything correctly.

Comment: This all appears correct.  Sometimes your intuition can be wrong and it is through repeated practice like this that you can learn to correct it.